# joda DateTime format cause null pointer error in spark RDD functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The exception message as following

> User class threw exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 
>   1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 11, 10.215.155.82): java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone.getInfo(CachedDateTimeZone.java:143)
>   at
>   org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone.getOffset(CachedDateTimeZone.java:103)
>   at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:676)
>   at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:521)
>   at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeFormatter.java:625)
>   at
>   org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime.toString(AbstractDateTime.java:328)
>   at
>   com.xxx.ieg.face.demo.DateTimeNullReferenceReappear$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DateTimeNullReferenceReappear.scala:41)
>   at
>   com.xxx.ieg.face.demo.DateTimeNullReferenceReappear$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DateTimeNullReferenceReappear.scala:41)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:328)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:327)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer$$anon$1.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:113)
>   at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.groupBy(TraversableLike.scala:327)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.groupBy(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
>   at
>   com.xxx.ieg.face.demo.DateTimeNullReferenceReappear$$anonfun$3.apply(DateTimeNullReferenceReappear.scala:41)
>   at
>   com.xxx.ieg.face.demo.DateTimeNullReferenceReappear$$anonfun$3.apply(DateTimeNullReferenceReappear.scala:40)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157) at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157) at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

My code as following:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.{ DateTimeFormat, DateTimeFormatter }




object DateTimeNullReferenceReappear extends App {

  case class Record(uin: String = "", date: DateTime = null, value: Double = 0.0) 

  val cfg = new Configuration
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.setAppName("bourne_exception_reappear")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val data = TDWSparkContext.tdwTable(   // this function just read data from an data warehouse
  sc,
  tdwuser = FaceConf.TDW_USER,
  tdwpasswd = FaceConf.TDW_PASSWORD,
  dbName = "my_db",
  tblName = "my_table",
  parts = Array("p_20150323", "p_20150324", "p_20150325", "p_20150326", "p_20150327", "p_20150328", "p_20150329"))
  .map(row => {
    Record(uin = row(2),
      date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime(row(0)),
      value = row(4).toDouble)
  }).map(x => (x.uin, (x.date, x.value)))
  .groupByKey
  .map(x => {
    x._2.groupBy(_._1.toString("yyyyMMdd")).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)   // throw exception here
  })

//      val data = TDWSparkContext.tdwTable(  // It works, as I don't user datetime toString in the groupBy 
//      sc,
//      tdwuser = FaceConf.TDW_USER,
//      tdwpasswd = FaceConf.TDW_PASSWORD,
//      dbName = "hy",
//      tblName = "t_dw_cf_oss_tblogin",
//      parts = Array("p_20150323", "p_20150324", "p_20150325", "p_20150326", "p_20150327", "p_20150328", "p_20150329"))
//      .map(row => {
//        Record(uin = row(2),
//          date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime(row(0)),
//          value = row(4).toDouble)
//      }).map(x => (x.uin, (x.date.toString("yyyyMMdd"), x.value)))
//      .groupByKey
//      .map(x => {
//        x._2.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
//      })

  data.take(10).map(println)

}
```

So, it seems that call **toString** in the **groupBy** cause the exception, so can anybody explain it?

Thanks

Comment: Well... `NullPointerException` occurs  when you try to call any function on a variable that holds a `null` values of any type. So... this means that in your `x._2`  there is some tuple in which the first member ( `_._1` ) is `null`.

Comment: Could you add the result of this?

`TDWSparkContext.tdwTable(   // this function just read data from an data warehouse
  sc,
  tdwuser = FaceConf.TDW_USER,
  tdwpasswd = FaceConf.TDW_PASSWORD,
  dbName = "my_db",
  tblName = "my_table",
  parts = Array("p_20150323", "p_20150324", "p_20150325", "p_20150326", "p_20150327", "p_20150328", "p_20150329"))
  .map(row => {
    Record(uin = row(2),
      date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime(row(0)),
      value = row(4).toDouble)
  }).map(x => (x.uin, (x.date, x.value)))`

Comment: Just replace this `groupBy(_._1.toString("yyyyMMdd"))` by `groupBy( d => { if ( d._1 != null ) { d._1.toString("yyyyMMdd") } else { "I am a placeholder" } })`. You can choose to do whatever you want with your place holders.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh  `map(x => (x.uin, (x.date.toString("yyyyMMdd"), x.value)))` this does not throw exception, is that `RDD.map` catch the null pointer exception, but `Array.groupBy` does not?

Comment: Well... Yes. Spark performs a lot of cleaning on the mapping function to wrap it in a "safe" closure before actually serializing it and mapping the RDD. The cleaning function is - `def clean(func: AnyRef, checkSerializable: Boolean = true)` defined in `ClosureCleaner.scala` ( https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala ). I am not really sure... but may be that also safeguards against `NullPointerExceptions` and just generates a `null` value for such cases.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I have experiment your the null-check solution, i am sorry that it does not work,:-(

Comment: And what is the error log in this expreriment ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh It still throws the null-pointer exception, even I use `.filter(null != _._1)`, before processing

Comment: Also... can you look into your Joda-time jar and paste the code of `org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone.getInfo` method with line numbers. Because the recent code of Joda time shows that line 143 is a blank line. So I don't know whats causing the problem.

Comment: Ok... well so it seems that the problem is being caused by `Info info = cache[index];` ( https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/tz/CachedDateTimeZone.java#L143 ) which means that `cache` is somehow `null`. I guess this should be a ticket against JodaTime .

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Joda-time in some way. For now you can just avoid using `.toString` and think of some other way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to either disable Kryo, use [Kryo JodaTime Serializers](https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers), or avoid serializing the DateTime object, i.e. pass around Longs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is bad serialization of Joda's `CachedDateTimeZone` - it includes a transient field that doesn't get serialized, remaining `null` in the deserialized object.

You can create and register your own `Serializer` that handles this object properly:

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone;

public class JodaCachedDateTimeZoneSerializer extends Serializer<CachedDateTimeZone> {

    public JodaCachedDateTimeZoneSerializer() {
        setImmutable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public CachedDateTimeZone read(final Kryo kryo, final Input input, final Class<CachedDateTimeZone> type) {
        // reconstruct from serialized ID:
        final String id = input.readString();
        return CachedDateTimeZone.forZone(DateTimeZone.forID(id));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final Kryo kryo, final Output output, final CachedDateTimeZone cached) {
        // serialize ID only:
        output.writeString(cached.getID());
    }
}
```

Then, in your class extending `KryoRegistrator`, add:

```
kryo.register(classOf[CachedDateTimeZone], new JodaCachedDateTimeZoneSerializer())
```

This way you don't have to disable Kryo or refrain from using Joda.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know much about the "problem". So we can try following experimat which will let us see more about the problem.

Replace the following part,

```
map(x => {
  x._2.groupBy(_._1.toString("yyyyMMdd")).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)   // throw exception here
})
```

With this,

```
map( x => {
  x._2.groupBy( t => {
    val dateStringTry = Try( t._2.toString( "yyyyMMdd" ) )
    dateStringTry match {
      case Success( dateString ) => Right( dateString )
      case Failure( e ) => {
        println( "=========== Null Tuple Description ==========" )
        println( "Problem Tuple :: [" + t + "]" )
        println( "Error Info :: [" + e.getMessage + "]" )
        // finally the stack trace, if needed
        // e.printStackTrace()
        prinln( "=============================================" )
        Left( e )
      }
    }
  } )
} )
```

Let's check the result of running this experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that `DateTime` looses something when serialising in Spark (which happens a lot there I guess). In my case the `Chronology` was messed up which caused the same exception.

One really very hacky workaround which worked for me is to recreate the `DateTime` just before using it, e.g.:

`date.toMutableDateTime.toDateTime`

This seems to restore whatever missing bits and everything is working after that.

The solution posted by Marius Soutier to disable Kryo also worked for me. This is a less hacky approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4170

Basically, you shouldn't be extending `scala.App` for your main class. It may not work correctly in some cases. Use an explicit `main()` method instead.

Here's the documented warning in the Spark 1.6.1 code (In `SparkSubmit` class)

```
// SPARK-4170
if (classOf[scala.App].isAssignableFrom(mainClass)) {
  printWarning("Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly. Use a main() method instead.")
}
```