# Error when broadcasting Joda DateTime in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jodatime

When using Joda Time with Spark, the code below causes `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
val todayBroadcast = sc.broadcast(new DateTime())
val dataRDD2 = dataRDD.filter(item => {
                                todayBroadcast.value.minusMonths(1).isBefore(item._1)
                              })
```

On the other hand, the code below works with no issues

```
    val dataRDD2 = dataRDD.filter(item => {
                                    val today = new DateTime()
                                    today.minusMonths(1).isBefore(item._1)
                                  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Joda has some problem with default serialization offered by Apache Spark. In particular the problem is with the Kryo serializer.

You can have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890375/joda-datetime-format-cause-null-pointer-error-in-spark-rdd-functions) SO thread.

Anyway, try to disable the Kryo serialization and use the standard Java serializer `org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer`. You can find the property `spark.serializer` inside the `spark-defaults.conf` of your Spark installation.

Now, you should have the following property:

```
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

that you have to change to

```
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
```

Then, restart you Spark installation. If you're using some particular distribution (i.e. Cloudera), change the above property using the administration console they give you.

If you can't use the standard serializer, you can transform you `DateTime` in  some other serialization-friendly format, like a `String` or a `Long` (time in milliseconds)

Let us know.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the standard serializer is too slow. Worst case scenario, I will get the date inside the filter function.

Comment: well, I could broadcast a string and then convert it back to date

Comment: Ok, but have you verified what I've said? You can broadcast the time in millis (Long) to overcome the problem

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using Kryo serialization with joda date time, you can do this instead. This uses already created serializers from https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers

Create a class that extends KryoRegistrator

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator

class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {

  import de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.jodatime.{JodaDateTimeSerializer, JodaLocalDateSerializer, JodaLocalDateTimeSerializer}
  import org.joda.time.{DateTime, LocalDate, LocalDateTime}

  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[DateTime], new JodaDateTimeSerializer())
    kryo.register(classOf[LocalDate], new JodaLocalDateSerializer())
    kryo.register(classOf[LocalDateTime], new JodaLocalDateTimeSerializer())
  }
}
```

Then register that class with the sparkconf

```
set("spark.kryo.registrator", "MyRegistrator")
```

This will serialise joda date time, local dates properly

Look at documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/tuning.html -> Data Serialization