# Spark Scala create pair RDD with sorted Date values

Tags: scala, sorting, datetime, apache-spark, rdd

caveat: i am new to spark and scala. i've found a handful of questions on Stack Overflow that are very similar to mine, but haven't been able to translate those into my problem.

Context. I have a pair RDD initially with records of the form (id, date) and I want to create an RDD of the form (id, last_date_seen). In the raw data, the date is a string and i've used Joda to convert to a `DateTime`.

I have successfully done this using `combineByKey`, and I understand that `groupByKey` is inefficient and this might not be practical in big cases, but I'm trying to understand approaches using the range of calls.

What i want to do is `groupByKey` and then `mapValues`, taking the list of values produced by `groupByKey` to get the max in the list.

What i've tried:

(I created an ordering on DateTime based on a different Stack Overflow question, so there is an ordering.)

I've tried a number of approaches, and most give me an exception that the task is not serializable. One example is,

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(_.toList.sorted.last)
```

I've tried any number of variants of this ;)  Without the `toList`, I get an exception that sorted is not a member of `Iterable[org.joda.time.DateTime]`. I'm successful in using `mapValues` and doing simpler things, but once I try to add sort, things go bad. I tried `sortBy` and specifying the `Ordering`.

Insights into why things sent to the sorted method aren't serializable would be helpful to me overall. I'm not sure how to recognize when I'm falling into this trap.

One of the Stack Overflow questions that was similar suggested that instead of using `mapValues`, you could just use `sortBy` and specify that it was on the second element, so `.sortBy(_._2)`. This also failed for me.  Ideally, if it made sense to do it that way, I'd like to know that too.

This seems like a really straightforward and probably common thing to do, so I feel like I'm missing something.

Edit - added for further detail of the exception. Note though that I wasn't able to reproduce this error.

The not serializable errors in the error stack indicate that the implicit ordering i had used, found in another Stack Overflow was the culprit. Note that I was not able to reproduce this error that aggrivated me for hours (see answer).

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:    
$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$Joda$
Serialization stack:
  - object not serializable (class:  
  $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$Joda$, 
  value:       $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$Joda$@6fc2db37)
  - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, 
 name: Joda$module, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$Joda$)
```

The Joda module had been defined just before.

```
object Joda {
 implicit def dateTimeOrdering: Ordering[DateTime] =  
   Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isBefore _)
}
```

Comment: Just `rdd.reduceByKey((x, y) => if(x.isAfter(y)) x else y)` and make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/33439328/1560062

Comment: thanks @zero323. another more compact version of the combineByKey that i hadn't tried. it seems like running into serialization issues is common in Spark, and so even though i've now got multiple solutions for my little exercise, i'd like to understand better why doing things with toList and sorting throw errors. maybe my question should really be recast to what causes the serialization error.

Comment: For serialization issues you should really check the linked question. Joda classes are really not Spark friendly.

Comment: thanks, @zero323. i had read that, but hadn't fully digested it and wanted to  go back, reproduce the errors, and confirm that they were the linked to DateTime by doing the same map with a different type of value. Unfortunately, i couldn't reproduce the error. i replicated my shell history exactly. the orig exception said that object Joda, which was the implicit ordering i defined, was not serializable; but doing it all again, no problem.  feel like i should delete this question, since i can't reproduce the issue, but wanted to ensure you knew i did follow up. sigh.

Comment: You could document that with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question really had two components:
* how to transform the RDD using groupBy in order to retrieve the last seen date for each id, and 
* why was the approach I tried giving a "task not serializable" error.

Unfortunately, after restarting the spark-shell and retracing my steps, i was unable to reproduce this error. The code I had listed in the question, paired with the DateTime ordering I had already established worked fine. I recently had another issue like this for which i was able to trace it down to a conflict in implicit values that i had set earlier in the shell for totally different purposes. i suspect this was also the culprit here, but wasn't able to verify that.

The other Stack Overflow question referenced in the comments indicates that the Joda have caused issues for others.

For completeness, I am able to do the transform and extract the last date seen several ways. The most straightforward being that given by @zero323 in their comment using reduceByKey.

Using groupByKey, the code in the question

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(_.toList.sorted.last)
```

works fine when the implicit ordering below is in place:

```
object Joda {
   implicit def dateTimeOrdering: Ordering[DateTime] =  
   Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isBefore _)}
import Joda._
```

similarly,

```
rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList.max)
```

results in the same.

I've also replicated the results using an ordering defined and passed to sorted explicitly.

Unfortunately, I was unable to determine why the object Joda threw an exception in the first session and didn't in the next many I tried.